# How separate huge texts using delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I would like to know a better solution for my problem. I'm pulling a huge text from a pdf file (1500 pages). And inside the PDF, i have several documents that i need separate using an array, example:

```
let docs = [
  [], <- doc1
  [], <- doc2
  [], <- doc3

  ... and so on...
];
```

Currently, i'm using regex to identify the beginning and the end.

```
let result = pattern.exec(REGEX);
docs.push(result[1]);
```

Most of the documents is very similar , with fixed fields with dynamic information. But some of them can vary in the end, which causes the regex pull two documents instead of one.

Is there a better approach for this? Or do i need add which possible delimiter (start of text and end)?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not related with my question @mplungjan

Comment: Where did i said that i'm parsing the text in the client?? The question is about delimiters, not parsing.

Comment: My bad. Missed the node tag

Comment: What is your regex? Besides, you shouldn't pass your regex object to exec method as an argument. exec is a method of your regex object. Hence you just call exec upon the regex object and pass your huge string as a parameter. I would recommend you to work in a few thousand word chunks though.